# Why I cannot use await for function in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I have below function in test.js file

```html
module.exports.connected = connected;

async function connected() {

    const mysql = require('mysql');
    const connection = await mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'localhost',
        user     : 'root',
        password : 'root',
        port     : 3311
    });

    await connection.connect(function(err) {

        if (err) {
            console.log("cannot connect to database");
        }

        console.log("connected");

    });

};
```

And use below code for call it

```html
const sql = require('./my_mysql');

sql.connected().then(function (data) {
    console.log("aaa");
});
```

But why is it printed "aaa" first and then "connected"?

While must wait for a response

Answer (score 2):

You can't use await for function because,
**The await operator only makes sense in an async function.**

Comment: Can you give me a example?

Comment: Please go through This: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function